# Is it possible to generate a splatmap out of a hand sculpted terrain?

Tags: texturing

I've sculpted a terrain which for artistic reasons has to be hand made.

Now, I'm wondering if maybe there's some type of shader I could do to generate a splatmap from this terrain, so I can use these as a starting point for my texture masks.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are there any particular maps that you interested in? Splat maps can be used for many things. A Height-gradient or a Facing-up-gradient are trivial for example.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is take a hand sculpted terrain, and create a series of texture masks so that I can use them to distribute materials on the level automatically based on a set of parameters. 

Ideally I would take my sculpted terrain to something like World Machine, and generate a texture mask to distribute materials based on slope angle, and things like that, so I can get a more realistic result.